# flutter 1.23.0-18.1pre BottomNavigationBar deprecated 'title' use 'label'

Tags: flutter

The `title` part is giving an error telling me that i should use label instead.

The Error is:

> info: 'title' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use "label" instead, as it allows for an improved text-scaling experience. This feature was deprecated after v1.19.0.. (deprecated_member_use at lib/Screens/hostHomePage.dart:49)

Hopefully someone can help me out?

```
BottomNavigationBarItem _buildNavigationItem(
      int index, IconData iconData, String text) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        iconData,
        color: AppConstants.nonSelectedIconColor,
      ),
      activeIcon: Icon(
        iconData,
        color: AppConstants.selectedIconColor,
      ),
      title: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: _selectedIndex == index
              ? AppConstants.selectedIconColor
              : AppConstants.nonSelectedIconColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you have an error, quote it in full in your post.

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: OK, so what about it seems unclear to you? It says you should use a newer feature instead

Answer (score 1):

As I see in the documents the things you are mentioning are correct and to have it working you must use label and pass a string to it. And remove the title parameter wherein you pass a widget.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem _buildNavigationItem(
  int index, IconData iconData, String text) {
return BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Icon(
    iconData,
    color: AppConstants.nonSelectedIconColor,
  ),
  activeIcon: Icon(
    iconData,
    color: AppConstants.selectedIconColor,
  ),
  label: text
);
}
```

This code should work out for you instead of the one you are writing right now. :-).

[link to the newer documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

This gives the following errors:
error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [travelapp] lib/Screens/hostHomePage.dart:49)

info: 'title' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use "label" instead, as it allows for an improved text-scaling experience. This feature was deprecated after v1.19.0.. (deprecated_member_use at [travelapp] lib/Screens/hostHomePage.dart:49)

Comment: sorry it was a little typo from my end. instead of title use label. that was the whole point of your question and i messed it up sorry ;)